# Casting SecureSocketOptions to integer to store in database

Tags: c#, enums, mailkit

I am attempting to save the SecureSocketOptions for MailKit in the database. I thought because it was an enum value, I could store it as integer and set it from there but I'm having no luck.

```
      var sso = new SecureSocketOptions();
      sso = emailSettings.SecureSocketOption;

      client.Connect(defaultEmailSetting.EmailServer, defaultEmailSetting.EmailPort, sso);
```

It says not able to cast SecureSocketOptions to integer.

Am I going at this wrong? I just want to save the setting to the emailsettings table and make it easy to set.

I have a feeling I'm overthinking this. Any suggestions?

**EDIT1**

For those suggesting casting to int, this is what happens when I try that:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can do this like an example

```
 int ssoValue = (int) SecureSocketOptions.Auto;
```

The enum has all these values:

```
- None  0
- Auto  1
- SslOnConnect  2
- StartTls  3
- StartTlsWhenAvailable 4
```

So, ssoValue will return 1 in this case.

```
int ssoVal = (int) sso;
```

Answer (score 0):

I was overthinking it.

I cast it as SecureSocketOptions like this:

```
var sso= (SecureSocketOptions) emailSettings.SecureSocketOption;
```

thanks all for your help!